# jest is not creating files for snapshots it add it inline to the testing file

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, snapshot

I'm trying to write tests for a react js app with jest
when I write a snapshot test jest does not create files for snapshots it adds it inline to the testing file like this

```
  test("it matches snapshot",()=>{
const tree = renderer
.create(<Button lable="click me"></Button>)
.toJSON();
expect(tree).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<div
className="button-style"
data-testid="button"
>
 click me
</div>
  `);
});
```

how to create a snapshot file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you already know by now that it's because you call `toMatchInlineSnapshot`. This method writes the content of the snapshot directly into the test file: https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#inline-snapshots. To save a snapshot into a separate file you need to call `toMatchSnapshot` instead.